# Heatmap is not showing missing value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am working to find-out the missing value of dataframe(that is train).I used pandas .isnull and it give me correct boolean output for missing value in 'Age','Cabin' and 'Embarked' columns.But when i used sns.heatmap ,it is not showing missing value for 'Embarked'.What I am doing wrong? please help me.Below are the image for better understanding.

[image: using pandas isnull]

[image: finding missing value]

Not showing missing value for Embarked in heatmap
[image: Not showing missing value for Embarked in heatmap]

Comment: how many are NaN in embarked?

Comment: try `train.isna().sum()` it could be that there are very few missing and the plot might have to downsample and thus leaves them out. i.e. if there are 860 samples in your data and there are fewer than 860 pixels in the vertical axis of your plot... you can also try setting the figure size of your image to be larger.

Comment: only 2 NaN value in embarked and tarin.isna().sum() not working in seaborn showing error code:Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by resizing fiqure:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

sns.heatmap(train.isnull(),cbar=False)
```

Thanks Stupidwolf for suggesting me.
[solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T3LQ.jpg)

Comment: Had the same issue and this solved it. Very odd that it doesn't warn you when it can't display the whole figure!